# Display current time of twitch video

Tags: javascript, video, time, twitch

So i have this Twitch video (past broadcast) that i want to show on my webpage. Now i want to show the current time of the video when it is playing. There is this function that returns this time but i can't get it to show in "realtime" (you actually see it running). I can only get it to show the current time after i perfom an action.

```
<script src= "http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>

<div id="play"></div>
<div id="time"><span>kp</span></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        width: 854,
        height: 480,
        video: "v113523217"
    };
    var player = new Twitch.Player("play", options);

    //this just returns 0
    var test = player.getCurrentTime();
    $('#time').append(test); 

    //this works
    $('span').click(function() {
        var test = player.getCurrentTime();
        $('#time').html(test);
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible to show a running timer of the current time of the player? I might also want to do some stuff depending on the remaining time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to update every second:

```
setInterval(function(){
 var test = player.getCurrentTime();
  $('#time').html(test); 
  //if you want to show something after 1 minute (for example):
  if(test>60000&&test<61000){
   alert("one min");
  }
},1000);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Was a little worried about performance using this but this is doing the job just fine :)

Comment: @Luffyyyyy glad to help. Timers in js  are added to the qeue, they are executed when js has no job...